# Adding location as predictor variable to control for sampling design when location is correlated with predictor variables

Tags: regression, biostatistics

I'm working on project where I want to test how good remote sensing data explains variation in different vegetation characteristics observed in the field. One of the response variables is soil pH indicated by the mean Ellenberg indicator value for soil reaction.

My sampling design was as following: I delimited two areas with forest. One area dominated by poor conifer forest, the other area dominated by broadleave forest growing on rich soils. The areas are in the same region. Inside each location random plots were generated, and field data was collected. Now, I've used linear regression to test the relationship between the response and the predicor variables (glm in R). And I have added location as a predictor (fixed effect?) to account for the sampling design. However, I notice that the location variable is highly related to some important predictor variables. For example, the presence of marine clay. The area with the broad leaved forest is the only location situated on marine clay. This seems to be the reason for the generally richer vegetation here compared to the other location.

My questions are: If I add location and clay in the same model, am I not introducing issues similiar to multicollinearity?  Is there another way to account for location, that is more proper?

Some more information: the data sample size is 56 (36 plots in the conifer forest and 20 in the broad leaved forest). The two locations are located 55 km apart. Below is the data structure of the mentioned variables. I haven't included all variables. I'm also working with continuous predictors...

```
 $ clay1           : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ location        : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","N": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ph.ellen.species: num  2.29 2.9 2.78 1.8 1.67 ...
```

Comment: Could you explain how including location in your analyses would be of any relevance to your scientific question?  After all, if it is, then your question *necessarily* concerns *only those two locations* and you cannot possibly draw inferences about any other locations.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: thank you for your response.
The only relevance of adding location is to account for the sampling design. The sampling design leads to the plots being distributed kind of in a clustered way. One cluster in the conifer forest and one in the broad leaved forest. So I thought I had to account for this somehow?